# Git: remove folder from history except for one author

Tags: git, git-filter-branch, git-rewrite-history

How can I remove a folder from every commit in the history but those of a particular author ?

Example : 
Authors `A` and `B` both modified the folder `app/`. I need to remove (in the history) every contribution of `B` to the folder but not those of `A`.

Comment: What should happen in the case when the author whose commits should be kept has a commit which changed something committed by another person.

Comment: @Lajos Arpad, manually fix conflict ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `git filter-branch` or BFG

### `git filter-branch`

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
    if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME" = "<commiter A>" ];
    then
            // remove any required data and re-commit it again
            git commit-tree "$@";
    else
            git commit-tree "$@";
    fi' HEAD `
```

### BFG

https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

[image]